# Blank page with react build

Tags: reactjs, deployment, build, production, react-scripts

I am facing blank page issue when the build is run. `npm run build`. I served the build locally to test out before deploying to test environment, it showed blank page.
The methods I tried so far-

```
1. homepage: '.' in package.json
2. baseline for BrowserRouter but my base route is '/', just gave it a try anyways
```

`package.json`

[image]

Please let me know if you need any other code, thanks!

Comment: check the browser console on the blank page, it may have some errors

Comment: Is there any index.html in your project?

Comment: please get screen shot when build done, and browser console

Comment: @tanmay There are no errors.

Comment: @MehradFarahnak you mean to say screenshot built logs and browser console logs?

Comment: @Mohit I do have it, do I need to check anything inside it like path to access to static files?

Comment: @vam, yes please

Comment: Can you share your index.html file? I think you're missing root path that you need to provide in your html for your application to bootstrap. If I'm not wrong that you need to provide using base tag. See this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

Comment: Also please check that your index.js should contain the same id given to your root div inside your index.html page. Because before rendering, we do document.getElementById(<ID of root element inside index.html>) in index.js

Comment: @Mohit index.html after building the file or index.html of public?

Comment: There must be an index.html file in your project's root directory not the public one.

Comment: In my root directory, I am having index.js but in public, I have index.html.
This is my index.html of public https://imgur.com/a/RYCay69

Comment: Thanks everyone, the issue is resolved now!

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. The problem was inside the `manifest.json` in public folder. I had to update start_url to '.' from './index.html'. This is enabling to server to search the static files inside the build folder. Build folder, because `manifest.json` would also be present in build.

NOTE: Make sure, you cross check whether react-scripts is compatible with react and react-dom you are using. Sometimes this fixes too.